# Is this correct for cmp()?

Tags: python

I just came across this behavior but have not seen it explained anywhere.  I would think `float('-inf')` should be less than 0.

```
>>> cmp(0, float('-inf'))
1
```

Comment: what do you think cmp returns? compare with cmp(0, 1) for example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`float('-inf')` **is** smaller than `0`.

`cmp()` returns a positive value when the first argument is greater than the second. Since `float('-inf')` is smaller than `0`, that also means that `0` is greater than `float('-inf')` so you would *expect* `cmp()` to return `1`.

From the [`cmp()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp):

> Compare the two objects *x* and *y* and return an integer according to the outcome. The return value is negative if `x < y`, zero if `x == y` and strictly positive if `x > y`.

and also simply verified:

```
>>> cmp(0, -1)
1
```

Comment: Silly me, hopefully I save someone else from asking.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to know that `cmp(a, b)` is essentially the sign of `a-b`.  So it's +1 if `a > b`, -1 if `a < b`, and 0 if `a == b`.